# query that add summary rows on invoice table (summary by single invoice )

Tags: sql

Hi and thanks in advance to who will answer the following question:
is it possible to have a SQL query that add 2 summary rows on invoice table, at the single invoice level?
1st row to add = discount (that is a column)
2nd row to add = total (price - discount)

Table example:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

Comment: please tag your RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a union approach here:

```sql
SELECT InvoiceNo, date, price AS Summary, 1 AS pos FROM yourTable UNION ALL
SELECT InvoiceNo, date, discount, 2 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
SELECT InvoiceNo, date, price - discount, 3 FROM yourTable
ORDER BY InvoiceNo, pos;
```

Note carefully the introduction of the computed column aliased as `pos`.  This places price records before discount records, which in turn are placed before the record having the difference.

Answer (score 0):

We can go for CROSS APPLY with ORDER BY, as given below:

```sql
DECLARE @table table(invoice int, dval date, price int, discount int)

insert into @table 
values (1111,'2021-09-07',100,10)

select m.invoice, t.summary from @table as m
cross apply
( select * from 
(
values (price,1), (discount, 2), (price-discount, 3))as t(summary,ord)
) as t
order by t.ord
```

| invoice | summary |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | 100 |
| 1111 | 10 |
| 1111 | 90 |

Comment: @CCC, if it answers your question, please mark it as answer. It will be helpful for others in future.